# JS - fill an array via prototyping

Tags: javascript

I just read the following JS code and I got 2 questions:

1. Why isn't the container object declared as variable?
2. What is"Array.prototype.push.apply" for?

Javascript

```
 Container = function(title, used) {
  this.title = title;
  this.used= !!used;
  this.callbacks = [];
 };

Container.prototype.push = function() {
    Array.prototype.push.apply(this.callbacks);
};
```

Comment: 1) Because it's a mistake. Or was already declared somewhere else

Comment: 2) Have a look at [what `apply` does](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply). However, your Containers `push` method doesn't make too much sense, it's equivalent to `this.callbacks.push()` - without any arguments.

Comment: should be .apply(this.callbacks, arguments );

Comment: @Bergi, 1 aint no mistake. that's how you declare Objects.

Comment: @Octopus: There is no declaration, and there is no object. There's a function that is assigned to an undeclared variable.

Comment: 1) is valid if the code does not have a "use strict" directive. That's one of the reasons that "use strict" is a good idea.

Comment: to be fair, without "use strict"; in the code, we can't assume it's a mistake; some folks declare globals like that. it's likely poor practice, but i wouldn't go so far as to flag it a "mistake"...

Answer (score 0):

Apply sets the invoking object within the push function. But it doesn't seem to be used correctly here. More on the invoking object, constructor functions and prototype here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941